# Generating Public/Backend Key for AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I am trying to implement end-to-end encryption for the aws classic load balancer. I see this [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-endtoend.html) provided by AWs and I kinda followed all the instructions correctly except for the last one whic is to add the public key .ebextensions/https-backendauth.config. Can you please guide me on how can I generate the public/backend key? I am weak on ssl and I do understand certificate components to apply in an app however for this one I'm still not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to follow the instructions in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-ssl.html which is linked from the document you have above. The summary of the document is that you will need to create a self-signed certificate using the `openssl` tool.

Once you have created the self-signed certificate, if you've followed the guide word for word, you will have a file called `server.crt` which is your public certificate whose contents you can insert into `.ebextensions/https-backendauth.config`.

This process also requires that you upload your certificate information to your EC2 server. That process is described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance.html (also linked in the above document). The end result is that your certificate and private key files will be placed in specific locations on your EC2 instance.